# Eureka server se autorregistra cuando no debería hacerlo

Tags: spring-boot, eureka, java-17

Hace un par de días que noto este defecto y no sé si se debe a un error en mis configuraciones o a un problema de Eureka en sí.

Tengo configurado Eureka para que no se registre ni se instancie, sin embargo, cuando abro el dash de eureka en http://localhost:8761/, veo que existe una instancia suya generada.
Alguien sabe por qué me puede estar pasando esto?
Si me baso en mis configuraciones, esto no debería suceder.

Agrego que además estoy usando un configserver donde tengo todas las configuraciones y dentro del microservicio de eureka uso el archivo bootstrap.yml (en resources) para que se conecte al config server, esto funciona bien porque cuando corro la aplicación, en los logs me muestra que encontró la configuración en el puerto 8888, que es el que escogí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Config de Eureka**

```xml
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}
  
spring:
  application:
    name: eurekaServer
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
#    serviceUrl:
#      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

--> intenté con el serviceUrl y sin él

**Pom de Eureka**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dh</groupId>
    <artifactId>eurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eurekaServer</name>
    <description>eurekaServer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenidx a SOes. Como recomendación para la vida, siempre hay que comenzar por [la documentación](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/).

Ahí uno ve que el problema es que la propiedad se llama `register-with-eureka`, no `registerWithEureka`.

Yo uso este fragmento en el yml para configurar el comportamiento de cliente y servidor de ese microservicio sin lío

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
  server:
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
    max.time.for.replication: 30000
```

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo la instancia... no sé por qué.
La semana pasada no me pasaba esto... :S

Comment: @MariaEugeniaFerraro seguro que en el configserver se sirve la configuración modificada? Habría que ver (editando tu pregunta) qué dice el log de eureka cuando lo inicias, poniendo todo en debug...